# Hashmap for a table where columns are not fixed

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a table with fixed no. of rows and variable no. of columns.

```
id   target    city1  city2 city3
 1     100       90     50    40
 2     500       90     30    70
 3     600       40     80    20
```

The no. of cities may differ from division to division. So I cannot use an arraylist in this case. I tried using a hashmap but I dont know how to go about it.

ResultSet rs_id gives me all the ids .

ResultSet rs_cities gives me all the city names and city id.

ResultSet rs_details gives me the amount related to the particular id and city.

I think I will need a hashmap within a hashmap. Please can anyone help with how to go about it.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: How about a `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>` where every entry in the map is the row's index and a list of columns.

Comment: the `id` you have mentioned in the table is divisionId ?

Comment: @Rehman no it is not division id. The no. of id's are fixed

Comment: @Titus I tried using that too. But since the no. of cities are not fixed i am not able to map the city with the id

Comment: It is really unclear what you want to do here? What type of operations do you need to perform on that data structure?

Comment: Does it matter whether no. of cities are fixed or not ? Still not getting relationship between those entities

Comment: What are you trying to map? What is the key, what is the value?